# Can I run multiple blogs from my local machine

Tags: multisite, local-installation

OK I head that WP can now host more sites using one installation. I host my blog on my own computer using MAMP and latest WP.

But I can't find option to create another blog?

Comment: This is a job for the <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network">codex</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+set+up+wordpress+multi+site+locally">google</a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this simply, make sure your WordPress version is 3.0+.  It is always recommended that you have the latest.

First you need to activate the network:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Note that, as you are using a local installation, you won't have the choice to create your network in sub-directories as subdomains won't work.  By reading and following the information in the link above, you'll get what I mean.